# OpenCV why does setting a Mat equal to a decimal less than 1 not cause all of the values in the Mat to become 0?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I need help figuring out how OpenCV handles setting a matrix equal to something.

I have an 8-Bit Mat called Radiance that I want to tone map. Here is working code that accomplishes this for me, with K being the constant 450.

```
cv::cvtColor(radiance, radiance, CV_BGR2XYZ);
radiance = (K * radiance)/(1 + (K * radiance));
cv::cvtColor(radiance, radiance, CV_XYZ2BGR);`
```

This ***does not seem like it should work***, but it does. It will create a fully tone mapped image that looks great. However, if you try to do this method on the individual pixels, they become a decimal that is between 0 and 1, which truncates to 0. Here is an example of this -

```
cv::cvtColor(radiance, radiance, CV_BGR2XYZ);
int x = radiance.at<cv::Vec3b>(500, 500)[0];
x = (K * x)/(1 + (K * x));
std::cout << x << "\n";
```

The output of this is exactly what I would expect

```
0
```

I understand why the second snippet of code prints out a zero, but what is going on in the first part that allows it to tone map the image properly, and how can I recreate this on the individual pixel level?

Comment: I think OpenCV does not truncate the values but round them... at least on a small test I did... try in your second test to do std::round to the assignment of x (or add 0.5 ) and you may get the same results

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just define radiance as float matrix?

```
Mat radiance(m, n, DataType<float>::type);
```

So you can get a float

```
cv::cvtColor(radiance, radiance, CV_BGR2XYZ);
float x = radiance.at<cv::Vec3b>(500, 500)[0];
x = (K*x)/(1 + (K*x));
std::cout << x << "\n";
```